# trying to batch file xcopy data files of our backup recovery software

Tags: batch-file

Running this script

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Users\DNIOSB\Downloads 
set dst_folder=d:\test3
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

the file list includes items such as:
Okay so I added the file path to the files for example

```
d:\Backups\servername\D_VOL-b001.spf
d:\Backups\servername D_VOL-b001-i6271.spi
```

And it's still not working
So I have tested xcopy from the command line and I can complete this without an issue from the original folder to a different folder.
My problem is that this batch script doesn't seem to be reading the text file. I would greatly appreciate any help people can provide.
I have tried using " " on each item in the text list.

Comment: is that better?
Thanks

Comment: When you successfully tested `XCOPY`, had you already read the information found when entering `XCOPY/?` at the command prompt? If so, from all of the available options, why did you choose those two. **`/S`** copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones whilst **`/E`** copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Had you been copying directories at least one of those options doesn't belong there but since you're copying individual files neither are required. In fact the outdated `XCOPY` command probably isn't required over `COPY` either!